# Why i can't acess the properties of response by server when i open my react app in my smartphone?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, responsive

So i am trying to create a Chatting app using react . On login page when i try to read the response from server for any errors it works fine on my pc but it shows error on my smartphone saying " cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')

so on the login page of my react  app i try to read the response from server to check if the credantionals are right or is all the fields have valid inputs or not . I check it by looking at the status of the response object. it works fine on my pc but it crashes and give error when i try to do it on my smartphone.

if you wanna refer to my code then here's the github link : https://github.com/The-Harsh-Kaushal/CommX

Comment: Please add *relevant* code here and don't refer to external code repositories ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.